# Postgres DB suddenly logging all mod statements

Tags: postgresql, heroku, logging

We have a PostgreSQL DB on Heroku, without warning a few days ago it started logging all data changes as if the `log_statement` setting was set to `mod` which is having a massive impact on performance when we do our nightly batch updates.

I've checked the settings in the DB via the `pg_settings` view and using the Heroku CLI and it very clearly says the the `log_statement` setting is set to `ddl`.

We haven't made any changes to the DB or its settings. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how we can reset the log level?

Comment: Have you done the settings check while logged in to the same database as the same user as is experiencing the problem?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, yes, Heroku exposes a single set of credentials for its DBs which our services use. I've used them to login and check the settings. I've just done it again and run `SHOW log_statement;` which returns `ddl`

Comment: I think we've worked this out with the help of Heroku support. The `log_min_duration_statement` was set to 2000ms, a trigger on the table is causing some statements to take slightly over that duration. All the thousands of subsequent log lines in the same batch were being treated as part of the same "long" duration statement and were being logged. Increasing the duration of the setting has resolved the problem.